# RTE in touch UI AEM, @context='html' disabling the HTML tags surrounding it in Sightly

Tags: user-interface, touch, aem, rte, sightly

```
<h1 data-sly-test="${model.text}" data-sly-element="${model.texttag}">
  ${model.text @ context='html'}
</h1>
```

This is resolving all HTML tags that are inserted in to the RTE fields. But due to the `context` option, the `h1` tag is suppressed. I also tried using `span` tags around `${model.text @ context='html'}`. I still don't see the `h1` tag in the final HTML output.

Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sightly code will work correctly. The `context` expression option of the inner Sightly expression will not affect the outer `h1` element. Beyond the fact that you're liable to allow HTML markup within an `h1` element that you don't want, this Sightly code isn't your issue. Your `h1` will appear in the final output.

Even if `texttag` is not a valid String representation of an HTML element, Sightly will fallback to `h1`. Even if your AntiSamy XSS config is set to filter out `h1` elements, that will only affect your inner Sightly expression and not the outer `h1` element.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i see that issue, if i remove @context i can see h1 tag working, but not otherwise. if i enter like **"test${model.text @ context='html'}"** 'test' is coming up in h1 but not the sightly text.

Comment: What are the values of `text` and `texttag` when you see the issue?

Comment: text is kbc and texttag is empty

Comment: this issue is resolved, i used htmlRules and blockHandler.